# taskkill windows command prompt not killing all processes php

Tags: php, batch-processing, taskkill

I am running `Windows 7 64bit for WAMP 2` server.

I am running my program from `batch script` using `Windows Com Component` for ex:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe C:\wamp\www\test\command.php
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run($command, 7, false);
```

Now When I find how many `"cmd.exe"` programs are running, it list me all the processes using below command:

```
tasklist /svc /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe"
```

And then I kill them with below command using php script:

```
$output = shell_exec('taskkill /F /IM "cmd.exe"');
```

Here, what happens is, not all my `cmd.exe` windows getting closed.

What might be error in above code? `Some windows are closed, while some remains open which is executing the command.`

Please help.

Comment: It does work for me. Have tried running it as administrator ?

Comment: Yes, I am running as administrator. I see many other posts having same issue, not sure what will be exact solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution [though open for better suggestions]

First needs to `check and kill` if `php tasks exists`, then `command prompt will kill` :

```
// It will first list out all `php.exe` tasks running
$output = shell_exec('tasklist /svc /fi "imagename eq php.exe"');
print_r($output);
echo "<br> ------------------------------------ <br>";

// It will first list out all `cmd.exe` tasks running
$output = shell_exec('tasklist /svc /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe"');
print_r($output);
echo "<br> ------------------------------------ <br>";

// kills php.exe tasks
$php_output = shell_exec('taskkill /F /IM "php.exe"');
print_r($output);
echo "<br> ------------------------------------ <br>";

// kills cmd.exe tasks
$cmd_output = shell_exec('taskkill /F /IM "cmd.exe"');
print_r($output);
echo "<br> ------------------------------------ <br>";

die(ucfirst('all tasks killed'));
```

Hope it helps to all !